# SortedList CopyTo throws an error despite following documentation syntax

Tags: c#

I'm coding a simple console app as below and I'm getting the following error:

**'SortedList<int, Employee>' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo' and no accessible extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument of type 'SortedList<int, Employee>'**

This is in the `getAllEmployeesistAll()` method. AS part of the assignment, the method must return an Employee[] return type, hence the need to cast.

Appreciate any help!

Link to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.copyto?view=net-6.0

*When I put in a second argument (for the index start), I get an error saying no overload 2 arguments.*

```
using System.Collections;
using System;

namespace Collections
{
    public class Employee
    {
        private string employeeName;
        private int employeeId;
        private double salary;

        public string EmployeeName
        {
            get { return employeeName; }
            set { employeeName = value; }
        }

        public int EmployeeId
        {
            get { return employeeId; }
            set { employeeId = value; }
        }

        public double Salary
        {
            get { return salary; }
            set { salary = value; }
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeDAL
    {
        SortedList<int, Employee> employees = new SortedList<int, Employee>();

        public bool AddEmployee(Employee e)
        {
            try
            {
                employees.Add(e.EmployeeId, e);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public bool DeleteEmployee(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                employees.RemoveAt(id - 1);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public string SearchEmployee(int id)
        {
            var employee = employees[id - 1];
            return $"You have searched for: Employee ID #{employee.EmployeeId} - Name: {employee.EmployeeName}\nSalary: S${employee.Salary}";
        }

        public Employee[] GetAllEmployeesistAll()
        {
            Employee[] employeeArr = new Employee[employees.Count];
            employees.CopyTo(employeeArr);

            foreach (Employee e in employeeArr)
                Console.WriteLine($"Employee ID {e.EmployeeId}: {e.EmployeeName}, salary: S${e.Salary}");

            return employeeArr;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee ash = new Employee();
            ash.EmployeeName = "Ash";
            ash.EmployeeId = 1;
            ash.Salary = 100000;

            Employee lucy = new Employee();
            lucy.EmployeeName = "Lucy";
            lucy.EmployeeId = 2;
            lucy.Salary = 200000;

            EmployeeDAL employeeDAL = new EmployeeDAL();
            employeeDAL.AddEmployee(ash);
            employeeDAL.AddEmployee(lucy);
            Console.WriteLine(employeeDAL.SearchEmployee(1));
            //employeeDAL.DeleteEmployee(2);

            employeeDAL.GetAllEmployeesistAll();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code gives me a completely different error (and one I'd expect): `error CS0308: The non-generic type 'SortedList' cannot be used with type arguments`. If you've *actually* got an import for `System.Collections.Generic`, then the problem is that the `CopyTo` method you referred to is on the non-generic `System.Collections.SortedList` type, which is an entirely different type to the one you're using.

Comment: `CopyTo` expects an `Array` as it's first argument, however the error message seems to indicate you're attempting to use it with a `SortedList<int, Employee>` instead (though admittedly, It looks like this is not the case in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the question go to the class `ListedSorted`, but the error is about the class `ListedSorted<TKey, TValue>`.

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-6.0#methods), the class `ListedSorted<TKey, TValue>` don't have a method `CopyTo`.

To convert `ListedSorted<TKey, TValue>` in `TValue[]`, you can use LINQ method `ToArray` :

```cs
var employees = new SortedList<int, Employee>();
var employeesArray = employees.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me!! I've had another issue before where I was using a LINQ method when I wasn't supposed to. I'm a bit confused why there are so many different libraries to choose from and which one I should get my methods from. I'm just starting in c# and this is really frustrating me. Any advice?

Comment: @Mashie, C#/.NET is 20 year old... It has a long history. I agree, it is not easy for a neophyte. Fortunately, the Microsoft documentation is reasonably up to date and shows the most recent practices.